# Sinon stub for node-postgres client

Tags: node.js, typescript, sinon, stub, node-postgres

I'm writing a Node application in TypeScript which is querying a Postgres database. In the unit tests I'm unable to mock the query-function.

My unit code looks like this:

```
class MyClass {

  /* more stuff */

  async validate(event: any): Promise<boolean> {
    const client = new Client();
    await client.connect();

    const result = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "user_id" = '${user_id}'`);

    console.log(
      result
    );

    /* more logic */
  }
}
```

My unit test looks like this:

```
describe("...", () => {
  sinon.stub(pg.Client.prototype, "connect").resolves();
  let stub = sinon.stub(pg.Client.prototype, "query").withArgs(
    `SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "user_id" = '1234'`,
     sinon.match.any,
     sinon.match.any
  ).resolves("asdf");

  it("...", () => {
    await myClassInstance.validate(event);
  });
});
```

Not talking about the test expectations for now, what I would expect is "asdf" printed on the console. But I don't!

I've tried removing the `.withArgs(...)` completely and then I can see "asdf". (But obviously it doesn't help that much ...)

What I've also tried is printing `stub.lastCall` and I see

```
args: [ `SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "user_id" = 'user_with_verified_subscription'` ]
```

somewhere then ...

Removing the two `sinon.match.any` matchers don't help either because then the TS compiler is complaining that `Client.query` takes 3 arguments ...

Any help is highly appreciated!

Best regards,

Max

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution using `proxyquire` and `sinon`:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { Client } from 'pg';

class MyClass {
  async validate(event: any) {
    const user_id = 1;
    const client = new Client();
    await client.connect();

    const result = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "user_id" = '${user_id}'`);

    console.log(result);
  }
}

export default MyClass;
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import sinon from 'sinon';
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';

describe('60172091', () => {
  it('should valdiate', async () => {
    const pgClientStub = {
      connect: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      query: sinon
        .stub()
        .withArgs(`SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "user_id" = '1'`)
        .resolves('asdf'),
    };
    const pgStub = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => pgClientStub);
    const MyClass = proxyquire('./index', {
      pg: { Client: pgStub },
    }).default;
    const logSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    const instance = new MyClass();
    await instance.validate();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(pgStub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(pgClientStub.connect);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(pgClientStub.query, `SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "user_id" = '1'`);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(logSpy, 'asdf');
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
60172091
asdf
    ✓ should valdiate (2212ms)


  1 passing (2s)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! But How can you make sure 'asdf' is only returned with a certain query?
Say I want asdf for user A and qwer for user B.

Sorry, I didn't specify this in my OP.

Comment: @MaximilianFerdinandMüller Then you can use `.withArgs` API

Comment: In my case this doesn't work. I have to put two times sinon.match.any and then the stub isn't called.

Comment: @MaximilianFerdinandMüller Updated answer, add `.withArgs`. Works fine